# How to integrate the characters AL32UTF8 into a Java web application with GlassFish Server?

Tags: java, oracle, jsp, netbeans, glassfish

I have one application with JSP and servlets and I have problems with characters:
`á`, `é`, `í`, `ó`, `ú`, etc...(specials).

What may be the cause?

- I configured Oracle with AL32UTF8 and I checked all Data Base settings.
- I checked the Operating System and estimated that it's all correct.
- I made one application in PHP in connection with Oracle, and I don't have problems with the characters. It's perfect!!

I suppose that the cause could be the Web Server. I am using Netbeans and its incorporated GlassFish Server.